# LGPL版Qtを用いたアプリを公開する際の、ライセンス要項について

Tags: qt, qt5, ライセンス

現在，Qt LGPL版を用いてデスクトップアプリを開発しています．
開発したデスクトップアプリを公開するに当たってよくわからない点があるので，質問させていただきました．
Qt LGPL版のライセンス要項には，"Qtを使用していることを明記する必要がある．"とありますが，
具体的にはどのように表示すれば良いのでしょうか？
アプリ情報の使用ライブラリの項にQtを追加すれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

参考例としては、VirtualBoxやWiresharkがあります。
それに倣うと問題ないかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．VirtualBoxを参考にさせていただきました．